# Javascript HTTP client library

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does anybody know how to create a JavaScript command line Application that consumes a public API using a HTTP client library?

Which JavaScript http library should I use?

Answer (score 1):

[request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) will do the job. [xhr2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr2) also provides a nice `XMLHttpRequest` emulation for Node applications.

Comment: I am a JavaScript novice. Just give me a head start. Write just the start. O can take of from there.

Comment: just give me a head start

Comment: You can read the examples over there: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request